# Do Customer Org also require salesforce functions License? When installing an APP that is bulit using salesforce function

Tags: salesforce-functions

I'm quite new to the whole Salesforce infrastructure. My question is:

If I build an APP using Salesforce Functions License, and I utilise the salesforce function to create a managed released package app. Will the customer orgs, who install my app, will also have to purchase a salesforce Functions license separately? Or the license restrictions will be bypassed with my app?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: NOTE: I'm not an ISV partner

Answer (score 0):

Functions can't be packaged yet, but there are plans to support packaging in the future. And when this happens, yes, your customers will need to have access to a Functions license.

Comment: So, Let's suppose I've created an app for app exchange, and that app uses salesforce function features, Do my clients also need to purchase the salesforce functions license as well? Or does that license comes with my app, out of the box?

Comment: As of Today Functions can't be packaged, but I'll suppose that customers will need a license since a Function will run in their org.